# how to write PCRE expression into splunk syntax

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

I have created this PCRE regex expression

```
^CCC-(\S)+-\d{4,5}$
```

but when I try to use it in splunk with this

```
rex field=message.log  (?message)"^CCC-(\S)+-\d{4,5}$"
```

I am getting all events back. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Maybe  `source="message.log" | rex field=_raw "^CCC-(?<Result>\S+)-\d{4,5}$"`? Or if it is not the whole text in the message.log, `"\bCCC-(?<Result>\S+)-\d{4,5}(?!\d)"`?

Comment: Maybe you want to display the whole substring from `CCC` till 4-5 digits? Then include all the pattern into the named capturing group, `(?<Result>CCC-\S+-\d{4,5})`

Comment: my initial query is to look through all events with id =555.  Then I'm trying to look in message.log to apply the regex.  Typically, there should be a code like CCC-<errorname>-<4 digits>.  I'm trying to make sure to grab only those events . So right now I wrote "555" | rex field= "(?<Result>CCC-\S+-\d{4,5})" but still not getting the right events

Comment: Did you try with `field=_raw`?

Comment: Yes sorry, that's what I meant to type earlier.

Comment: Are you sure the regex matches what you expect?

Comment: I get a match in regex101 website when I test with string "CCC-TEST-1001"

Comment: The `rex` command is for extracting fields from events and requires at least one named capture group.  To filter events based on a regular expression, use `regex`.

Comment: Have you explored the syntax of the regex engine you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get results I needed using the rex command instead

```
rex field=message.log "(?<Result>(CCC\-(\S)+\-\d{4,5}))"
```